# Is it possible to say that every prime number is located in the interval $[2,1/x_{k}]$

Tags: general-topology, prime-numbers, compactification

We know that the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ is homeomorphic with the subspace $\{ 0 \} \cup \{ 1/n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \}$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

I have for all $1≤k<+∞$ the following inequality:

$$p_{k}≤1/x_{k}.............(*)$$ where $p_{k}$ is the prime sequence and $0<x_{k}<1$ is a strictly positive real sequence without lower bound, i.e., there is no real number $a>0$ verifying $a<x_{k}$ for all $1≤k<+∞$.  Here I understand that the inequality holds true for all finite primes. If $k=+∞$, then $x_{k}=0$.

But since $0<x_{k}<1$ is bounded, then in the usual topology of $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ inequality $(*)$ cannot holds for infinitely many primes.

My **question** is: By this one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$. Is it possible to say that every prime number is located in the interval $[2,1/x_{k}]$

Comment: I don’t see problems here. We interpret the compactifying point of $\Bbb Z_+$ as $+\infty$.
It is the limit of the sequence $\{p_k\}$. The inequality (*) holds for each $k<\infty$. For $k=+\infty$ the value $1/x_k$ is undefined. If for each finite $k$, $1/x_k$ is an integer, then the sequence $\{1/x_k\}$ has the limit $+\infty$ in the one-point compactification $\alpha\Bbb Z_+$ of $\Bbb Z_+$, so then we can interpret  $1/x_{+\infty}$ as $+\infty$. The interval $[2,+\infty]$ is undefined, but if we put  $[2,+\infty]=[2,+\infty)\cap\{+\infty\}$ then $p_k\in [2,+\infty]$ for each finite $k$.